# How to subversion commits make private

Tags: svn, commit, private

I have been working on a project shared in svn. I am working from home as well as from office. I wanted to commit some files from office privately (may be partial functionality) so that I can update the files from home and continue working from home . Private means no other svn user should be able to access my commits. These private commits are only for me to continue from where I left.

I know that Branching and tagging might be an  alternative option to keep private branches. But I would like to know any easier approaches

Answer (score 1):

Branching is the standard/accepted method of achieving what you want. Create a private branch and set up path-based authorization to only allow your account access to it. Make sure that you're merging from trunk regularly, and back to trunk as often as is reasonable.

Or, keep your working copy on a USB stick & work off that instead of maintaining separate working copies on each computer.

Answer (score 1):

Local repository with the same UUID, as "official"

For private commit you:

- switch your WC to local repo
- commit
- ...
- update Home-WC from local repo
- code
- commit

In office

- switch your WC to local repo
- update
- switch to official repo
- commit homework

Comment: 1.I need to maintain a local repo which is accessible from home and office right ?  2. How the local repo will be updated with commits from other developers from office ?

Comment: @santhosh - 1. local repo is repository on (movable) USB-stick, f.e, accessible with file:/// on both locations. 2. Repo is one-time thing - you create repo from official dump at evening and delete after importing work at morning